# Call function throught another file

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

View/Invoice/View.ctp

```
<?php

    if ( $payments == NULL ) {
        echo '<tr><td> -- No Payments Are Associated With This Invoice -- </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td></tr>';
    }

?>

<? foreach ($payments as $payment): ?>

    <tr id="payment_row_<?= $payment['id'] ?>">
        <td class="responsive_cell"><?php echo $payment['method']?></td>
        <td class="date_cell responsive_cell"><?php echo $payment['date']?></td>
        <td class="right responsive_cell"><?php echo number_format($payment['amount'], 2, '.', ',')?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php  $paymentsTotal += $payment['amount'] ?>

<? endforeach; ?>
```

View/Invoice/email.ctp

```
$bedrag = $settings['Setting']['currency'].$thisInvoice['Payment'];
```

This echo's  €Array in EMail.ctp and in View.ctp show the right amount.

How do i get the right amount in Email.ctp ?

Comment: Gonna need to clarify your question.  It's not clear at all.

Comment: Well, `$thisInvoice['Payment']` is an array, so `print_r($thisInvoice['Payment'])` to see what it looks like.